# Cleaning UTF-8 texts in Python from weird characters

Tags: python

I have texts parsed from websites and I need to clean them in Python for later NLP use. They are in Polish, not English, so I have UTF-8 characters like `ą`, `ł`, `ó` etc. I have to leave only normal punctuation (`.,'"-` etc.) and letters (inluding Polish characters) and remove all "weird", non-standard characters like `•` for example. How can I do that? I think that I need some regex and replace those non-standard characters with `""` (no character), but I don't know how to filter only "regular" charaters. The UTF-8 is a problem here, getting ASCII alphabet is easy.

Comment: Have a look into the `unidecode` package.  We use it for cases like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unidecode to turn your text into ASCII :

```
import unidecode
text = unidecode.unidecode(texte)
```

Then you can use this to filter some unwanted caracters :

```
for i in ("<",">","!","?","-","$",";","Ãƒ","Â©","_","-","Â«","Â»","*") :
    texte = texte.replace(i, " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the error handling options in `decode`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers

So where `content` is a `bytes` object containing the UTF8 text, something like:

```
content.decode("ascii", "ignore")
```

ought to do what you want.